# Disabling Windows Error Reporting(AppCrash) dialog programmatically

Tags: .net

I am executing a Process in .NET app.

```
                Process process = new Process(); 

....

                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
....
                process.Start();
```

The problem is that the executable sometimes crashes, which is OK, but the AppCrash dialg pops up and prevents the app to continue the execution until I click on close.

I know that I can set `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\` value Disabled to true -  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**But is there a way that I can do this in code?**

EDIT:

kmp has posted a great answer, but I am still looking how to achieve the same with native application.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you can edit the code of the crashing process then what you can do is add code like I show below to it (this article talks about it: [Disabling the program crash dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx)) - see [SetErrorMode function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the MSDN information about this Windows API function.

If you cannot alter the crashing application's code it is more complex and you would have to inject code into it at runtime (how complex that is depends on what the process you are launching is written in - if it is a .NET process it is easier than a native application for example, so you would need to give some more information about that process).

```
[Flags]
internal enum ErrorModes : uint 
{
    SYSTEM_DEFAULT = 0x0,
    SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 0x0001,
    SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT = 0x0004,
    SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX = 0x0002,
    SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX = 0x8000
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern ErrorModes SetErrorMode(ErrorModes mode);
}

// Ideally the first line of the main function...

NativeMethods.SetErrorMode(NativeMethods.SetErrorMode(0) | 
                           ErrorModes.SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | 
                           ErrorModes.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | 
                           ErrorModes.SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot alter the crashing process. The executable is a native code. The application is gswin64c.exe can be found in this archive: http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs906w64.exe

Comment: So, any idea how can I inject this into native application?

Comment: Works great. Maybe the injection is not necessary when dealing with managed application. You could create a wrapper app, that would set these flags and then load the real app assembly (not new process) and execute Program.Main() using reflection, but it is just an idea, I have not tested it.

Comment: worked for me.  I used this NativeMethods.SetErrorMode(
                           ErrorModes.SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX |
                           ErrorModes.SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);

Comment: is there a way to restart my application after crash ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463(v=vs.85).aspx) it should be possible to inherit the `SetErrorMode` value to the child process. So any kind of launcher (or your main app) that would `SetErrorMode` to required values and then execute your native app should work. Actually this inheritace exists by default. To turn it off see flags [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx).